# ASP.NET MVC Inline Edit

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

I am building an MVC 2 web app,  where I want to display information about something (the parent) as well as child details which are displayed as rows (children have a many to one relationship to the parent).

I have implemented AJAX in MVC before using Ajax.BeginForm and partial views
[Using this method - with minor changes for MVC 2 release](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/AJAX_Panels_with_ASPNET_MVC.aspx).

I want to add the ability to edit child rows inline using ajax, but I would like to know how others implement this.  Are there facilities in MVC that can do this?

Comment: No, nothing in MVC. How is an "inline" edit different from what you describe with partial views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [this post here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/). From what you're describing it's exactly what you need for your scenario. You can not only edit items inline but also add/remove item dynamically.

Comment: Very interesting post, thank you.  Nice and clean.  I am hoping to be able to do something similar, but edit one row at a time.  I think this is a good start and I can use it to get where I need to go.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a requirement for Javascript plugin or library than ASP.NET MVC..

If you want the behaviour where you click on link and get into edit mode (like replace text with textbox) take a look at [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable).

Though I don't use it, I just create (for example, in a table) one row with fixed text and another with textboxes and then hide the one with textboxes and I only display it when user click on Edit link. I have 
a save link in the edit row and when this is clicked I just hide the edit row. I post the data using regular form post not ajax post.